# Remove old logrotate entries

Tags: nginx, debian, logrotate

Recently I have removed nginx on my server running Debian Linux and since then, I keep getting the following email every day:

```
root@server:~# tail /var/mail/root
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/nginx/*.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

In some cases it helps to remove software with `dpkg --purge` but in this case the config files seems to be placed in some other place which won't be removed by dpkg. I've also walked through every config file of `logrotate` that I could find but I can't find anything regarding nginx.

So here is my `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` (nothing special):

```
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

And here is my `/etc/logrotate.conf` (I think nginx should be listed here?):

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
 missingok
 monthly
 create 0664 root utmp
 rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
 missingok
 monthly
 create 0660 root utmp
 rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

And also the linked directory `/etc/logrotate.d`:

```
root@server:~# ls -la /etc/logrotate.d
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 19 00:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 root root 4096 Mai 28 14:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  326 Mär  4  2013 apache2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  173 Nov 16  2013 apt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   79 Nov  7  2012 aptitude
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  232 Okt  1  2013 dpkg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880 Jan 20 16:36 mysql-server
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  163 Feb 17 10:32 php5-fpm
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  799 Sep 28  2013 proftpd-basic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  515 Mär  5  2013 rsyslog
```

So where is the config file for nginx? I think removing such a config file would solve my problem?

Comment: Try "grep nginx /etc/logrotate.d/*"
It's not out of the question that one of those other files has some reference to nginx, for some bizzarro reason

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I just got this message too (though just once)